# Is There a Way to Combine Similar Rows in SQL Based on a Value That Isn't Exactly the Same?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, database, merge

i have an SQL table that you can add brand names to, and when a new brand name is added, it will either increase the existing brand active count, or create a new brand name.

[image: the table looks like this:]

The problem is, if someone added a new brand with different spelling (like adding Toyota but spelled toyota) it would make a new brand with a new active count and new brand id. Now that the table has a few instances of this, is there a way i can sort through with SQL and merge the similar brands? I know this would end up deleting a few rows and I'm not sure if SQL has the power to do this all at once.

I'm still kind of new to SQL so any advice on this is appreciated. I heard that using Python Pandas would be easier so I am currently looking into that for a method to do this.

Comment: The normal way to handle this is at the UI layer: making it harder to add new brands (show an confirmation to be sure) and easier to match to existing brands (auto-complete, so using an existing brand is less typing).

Comment: and `collation` should be `case insensitive`

Answer (score 2):

In case of simple case changes, you can use functions like LOWER() to convert all of them to lower case and then group results together based on brand_name,
However, your question says "similar" records where similar is not so well defined. **The SQL language expects you to clearly define what you need**.

If you are looking to fix one / few characters you can use [LIKE operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) with percentage (`%`) and `/` or underscore (`_`) sign. You can define all permutations of errors you would like to identify by placing `%` and `_` at various positions. Alternatively, you can also explore [SOUNDEX function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-soundex-function.php)  or [sounds like](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-sounds_like-function.php) in MySQL and see if you can merge brand names based on SOUNDEX.

If data is not huge, I will suggest you to create another table / temporary table to perform such operation. This way, you can always refer back to original data.